# Is this some sort of scam or do I have stalker?

Tags: email, spoofing

Sender: msmith11@mail.com
Emails are from IP address:74.208.4.200

Emails are weekly. all text, no links, no images. Some Depict sexual fantasies in high detail directed to a female - which I am. 
Most recent email stated: wear red tomorrow.
I didn't wear red that day.
Next email stated: that wasn't very red, try harder tomorrow.

Trying to determine if it's some sort of ploy to get me to reply at which my email becomes compromised in some way? Or if I should be watching over my shoulder a little more and looking out for a creeper?
The IP address seems to be on the spam list when I google it. Email address seems generic or fake or spoofed.

Is there other source data in the email to help dig?

Any tips or guidance is appreciated.

Here's an email with all source info.
Its an older one..when I attempted to paste in one that had a lot more graphic content this site told me I was spamming and it wouldn't let me.

```
x-store-info:J++/JTCzmObr++wNraA4Pa4f5Xd6uensStKY2P46TrDiNfTinmuG66B1kxfqve/2MA8JS8RXbaxzm3yf6YIXD2rqIZc0WhwIWl/p1L+f4iXf2nVV1YNnm/jsljz7aLeeta3K+uNGtkU=
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=pass (sender IP is 74.208.4.201) smtp.mailfrom=MSMITH11@mail.com; dkim=none header.d=mail.com; x-hmca=pass header.id=MSMITH11@mail.com
X-SID-PRA: MSMITH11@mail.com
X-AUTH-Result: PASS
X-SID-Result: PASS
X-Message-Status: n:n
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTE7YT0xO0Q9MTtHRD0xO1NDTD0z
X-Message-Info: NhFq/7gR1vQ3/ySCLm+UU3K0MkFlT5F3PoTvE/eJ3d7NYFbWcBAaRj1WgObFwMdCskxBwQWS3ii2isDEH8z0x7nIDiTrEJsDLyyBEZPT1LTeiBmEfiUUmCM9dXzCj/LnbctD6hE+NJ1G3XvP13BvxkixB3OfQ7a3mC/MDqwfw4dGeFTbDYgRkCd4+vo3rC8XjECIkBKxd45+U4+dEiaSWSwc1QT8OUQW4jP9JexruBYekeCkh4htrA==
Received: from mout.gmx.com ([74.208.4.201]) by COL004-MC6F36.hotmail.com over TLS secured channel with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.5.7601.23143);
     Mon, 19 Oct 2015 14:01:19 -0700
Received: from [67.4.235.234] by 3capp-mailcom-lxa15.server.lan (via HTTP);
 Mon, 19 Oct 2015 23:01:18 +0200
MIME-Version: 1.0
Message-ID: <trinity-585081ab-4898-4a00-9379-fe56224dfd77-1445288478735@3capp-mailcom-lxa15>
From: "ML Smith" <MSMITH11@mail.com>
To: myemailhere

Subject: Thinking of you. Part 3
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 19 Oct 2015 23:01:18 +0200
Importance: normal
Sensitivity: Normal
X-Priority: 3
X-Provags-ID: V03:K0:GIcR2OMy3szCgVf9sqGX9G+qJ0IxUP8EHjgUXDwHq1+
 C1lfP+FviRU8qeDbucMVUkFxs408Pky+kqcL+EQSR6smvtD6l5
 bBDGRPIHrQmfKXTkNqlMk3CmwU2Gdpmknjv24Vabf3+dH2qSHw
 LofUvrClybCqUVNabt70NrkPftIFYjiciu4/UGjuKHyedVHQ2s
 npwXR96o9waL0EyVThvtr/TpsEV0omVt76T2khlNturf4Tf/0k
 V/XqayeYJlkLDPebUAWwfGfdNCfPU5fZdoaJLhvI7ROgkXVSpz
 TZcVOuhCXDTgMdv95803p2QijVW
X-UI-Out-Filterresults: notjunk:1;V01:K0:sF4+/cOPXrk=:hqKaETrfzG3ZMBDL6lp5es
 7WClsB/9spHemywn2JvIdGQszdHDSc5r3pgTx1XFB8y9S5ii45dHmzGOgVm2UiO6sLUnFJ88I
 NftaGS2DGI5/oaQlIIq2HIQMnbNdiKbjqFpvravnctHmDDrmUX1Qt28dXz2tqxjaxC1OhyuzJ
 5+IsbPt7+UtBaHAj6jZDUEVsSRUqsjO8yHMn7TOHzo5L22KQbt4jaaydeVlOiX7HmpSLYdtrg
 9p4JdeBm++Ah8l8NMlNsiOV6XjZwGEzozlv6tgLh4bi7duTIgfcEwG8Q/R6IfNtwsiUFJ0GfT
 t9rmRIx4ps79oZqoLPs5CDnZ+ZTJHvjRftwwGts6Bc9ZCOTR4WA8b+DZnltQoVZgGCBlwfT2e
 122Hg8CHMqPzwY7LwH9mLgjwv02jJSgk3zcVirevauRywGnhqenQ6ulFe9g/P9Ic140R/H1wP
 /isGoZvhXQ==
Return-Path: MSMITH11@mail.com
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 19 Oct 2015 21:01:19.0667 (UTC) FILETIME=[4D878030:01D10AB1]

<html><head></head><body><div style="font-family: Verdana;font-size: 12.0px;"><div>one day i&#39;ll walk up behind you and start massaging your shoulders and youll know it&#39;s me. ill finish and start walking slowly away. wait a few seconds, then follow. the hotel will already have been booked and it&#39;s only a block away. we can be back before anyone notices.</div>

<div>&nbsp;</div>

<div>its going to happen soon kitty kat</div></div></body></html>
```

Comment: Is it okay to post the content of the email?

Comment: If you're worried about a stalker, please go to the police.

Comment: If I were doing this to a group of people, I'd bet on most of them not wearing red. However, I would also bet on their starting to test me afterwards to see if I really was targeting them personally or a group. The easiest way to test this besides asking me would be to randomly either comply or ignore my requests and see if I responded accordingly. If that happened, I'd lose (on average) 1/2 of my targets per request. So, if I were targeting a group of people, I would make as few requests as possible after the first one. Just a thought.

Answer (score 6):

This appears to be coming from one or more scammers. By analyzing the mail headers it reveals the IP address: 67.4.235.234

[image: Mail header analysis]

In addition to that, it seems some internal information is disclosed from the sender: ***3capp-mailcom-lxa15.server.lan***

[image: Mail analysis reveals internal information]

http://mxtoolbox.com/Public/Tools/EmailHeaders.aspx?huid=a56c17eb-26ce-4d53-b030-e9f1a1447fec

By searching for this internal information disclosure, it revealed that this QWest customer is sending the emails (although it could be a compromised machine) and are found on scammer sites:

[image: Google Search the internal information disclosure]

Performing a WHOIS lookup on the IP address an abuse email address with instructions on how to send an abuse complaint is found:

[image: WHOIS query on the sender's IP address]

I suggest to fill out all the details that they want, including the mail headers (yes, multiple headers) and send a complaint to abuse@centurylinkservices.net

In addition, you could send them the link to this topic so they can see this analysis.

Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: I live in the surrounding area of Minneapolis, so if these emails are coming from the location found above than I would call that too close to home to ignore.  Qwest is a major service provider that is now Centurylink that is  in this area so it makes sense.

Comment: So what's your next step? Did you report it to Qwest / Centurylink? I wouldn't mind knowing the outcome of this.

Comment: The emails got more obvious that it was someone around me. I have taken steps to protect myself and involved professionals to address it. Thanks for your help all!

Comment: It could also just be a proxy, which would explain the spam results.

Answer (score 0):

First, mail.com is a legitimate webmail site.

Second, 74.208.4.201 is a PA, USA IP.

If you live in PA, I would escalate this to the police immediately. If you do not live in PA, I would still consider contacting your local police.

There isn't much more to dig out, from what I can see. From other types of spam like this, the intent is to start a dialogue, and then the spammer gets you to reveal more and more data.

But frankly, given the threatening nature of the emails, I'd talk to your local police. Besides, they have more tools to work with.